# Чи правильне слово "відпочиваючий"?

Tags: вживання-слів, розмовна-українська, дієприкметники

Недавно їхала поїздом "Київ-Трускавець" і почула жінку, що пропонувала "...квартиру для ***відпочиваючих***". Знаю, що тема активних дієприкметників неодноразово обговорювалась тут. Але власне такого слова я не зустріла. То ж чи є правильним вживати в розмовній мові слово ***"відпочиваючий"***?

Comment: за тегом [tag:дієприкметники] багато цікавого чтива на цю тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ВІДПОЧИВА́ЛЬНИК, а, чол. Той, хто відпочиває (в 1 знач.). Стоятиме курінь в саду над водою, кухар у білій намітці годуватиме відпочивальників компотом (Юрій Яновський, II, 1954, 194).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidpochyvaljnyk)